# Select a fixed columns in a VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with this VBA. Thanks in advance.

I want to select a range (of values, the whole column) for the values:
**FirstDate**, **EndDate** and **Number**.
My VBA:

```
Sub DateTest()
    Dim FirstDate As Date    ' Declare variables.
    Dim IntervalType As String
    Dim Number As Integer
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim TempDate As Date
    Dim i As Integer

    IntervalType = "m" ' "m" specifies MONTHS as interval.
    FirstDate = Cells(1, 1).Value
    EndDate = Cells(1, 2).Value
    Number = Cells(1, 3).Value  ' "Number" For the syntax DateAdd.

    ' If the number is not greater than zero an infinite loop will happen.
    If Number <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "Number needs to be greater than 0", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    i = 1
    Do Until TempDate = EndDate
       If i <= 1 Then
           TempDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, FirstDate)
       Else
           TempDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, TempDate)
        End If
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print i
    Loop
    Range("D1").Value = i - 1
End Sub
```

As I wrote before I want to run my Macro not only for the 1st cell (currently the macro works fine for the value  *(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)*), as you can see above for  **FirstDate**, **EndDate** and **Number** 
I wan to use for all dates in:
***Column1***, ***Column2***, ***Column3***

I made some changes, for example for EndDate:

> `EndDate = Format(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value)`

is not working, take the vale for 1 cell and the rest of the values in the column are ignored.

I tried:

> ```
>     FirstDate = Range("A1:A20").Select
>
>     EndDate = Range("B1:B20").Select
>
>     Number = Range("C1:C20").Select
> ```

But I get: "Number needs to be greater than 0"

Comment: Have you looked up how to apply [`.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)? Besides that, with your second attempt you'r trying to select a range while applying values to some variables at the same time? I think what you are trying to do is to loop through a range. Have a look around on internet and so. I bet there are some usefull examples to be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, see below:

```
 Sub DateTest()
    Dim FirstDate As Date    ' Declare variables.
    Dim IntervalType As String
    Dim Number As Integer
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim TempDate As Date
    Dim i As Integer

    IntervalType = "m" ' "m" specifies MONTHS as interval.

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    lLastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For lRow = 1 To lLastRow

    FirstDate = Format(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    EndDate = Format(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    Number = .Cells(lRow, 3).Value

    ' If the number is not greater than zero an infinite loop will happen.
    If Number <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "Number needs to be greater than 0", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    i = 1
    Do Until TempDate = EndDate
       If i <= 1 Then
           TempDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, FirstDate)
       Else
           TempDate = DateAdd(IntervalType, Number, TempDate)
        End If
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print i
    Loop
    Cells(lRow, 4).Value = i - 1
    'Range("D1").Value = i - 1

      Next
      End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably 2 issues in the code:

- Reading from Excel
- Business Logic

Concerning the reading from the worksheets, make sure that the parent worksheet is always mentioned. E.g., instead of writing `FirstDate = Cells(1, 1).Value` write `FirstDate = Worksheets("DatesWorksheetName")Cells(1, 1).Value`. Furthermore, this is a must-read topic for VBA - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

For the business logic, replace the value read from the worksheet with some standard values and give it a try until it works:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim tempDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim firstDate As Date

    firstDate = #5/19/2019#
    endDate = #11/19/2019#
    tempDate = #8/19/2019#

    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    Dim intervalType As String: intervalType = "m"
    Dim number As Long: number = 5

    Do Until tempDate >= endDate
        If i <= 1 Then
           tempDate = DateAdd(intervalType, number, firstDate)
        Else
           tempDate = DateAdd(intervalType, number, tempDate)
        End If
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print i
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Vityata thanks for your time, see I added    
   FirstDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
    EndDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value
    Number = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3).Value I get Run time error '5' invalid procedure call or agument.

Comment: @Lorenzo Castagno - I am afk now, but did you do the replacement in my code? Then it should work, I guess. Just to make sure - "Cells(1,3)" is "C1" and not "A3".